# Getting current version of webpage

Tags: python, linux, caching, wget

How do I get the current version of a webpage in Wget or Python? I need caching turned off completely.

I'm trying to write code to download http://robocademy.com/courses/arduino/get_code/ every second. With Python's urllib and Wget I'm not getting the current file like I am in Chrome. 
I've tried

```
wget --cache=off --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" http://robocademy.com/courses/arduino/get_code/
```

and urllib with urllib.urlcleanup

Response headers in chrome:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:449
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Wed, 28 Nov 2012 23:20:24 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Varnish:400211059
```

Response headers in Wget

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/plain
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2012 23:22:20 GMT
X-Varnish: 400216320 400212892
Age: 76
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: How do I get the current version of a webpage in Wget or Python?

Comment: You *are* getting the current version of the web page, as the server is configured to serve it. Do you have a specific reason why you want to override the server's configuration against its administrator's intentions?

Comment: It's my site. I need the current version because I'm making a web controller for robots and need to know asap if there's new commands to execute.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding `--no-cache` to wget. According to manual:

> Disable server-side cache. In this case, Wget will send the remote server an appropriate directive (‘Pragma: no-cache’) to get the file from the remote service, rather than returning the cached version. This is especially useful for retrieving and flushing out-of-date documents on proxy servers.
>
> Caching is allowed by default.

`cache=off` is supposed to go in `wgetrc` file.

For Python you can consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757251/1247955).

Comment: Are you sure about that? Question is: How do I get the current version of a webpage in Wget or Python?

Comment: @TimothyClemans no, line 4 of of your question states that you have tried `--cache=off` and not `--no-cache` ;) and line 6 of my answer states that `cache=off` should go into wgetrc file.