# python urllib.open(url) but return history data

Tags: python, session, cookies, web-scraping, urllib

I use python's urllib library for checking the update of one webpage every 5 sec.
But after I run the program a few hours, It seems that the urllib.open(url) just returns the outdated data.It usually delays by 5-10mins.I need your help.

```
    urlItem = urllib.urlopen("http://ka.game.163.com/")
    htmlSource = urlItem.read()
    urlItem.close()
```

Comment: Try to use urllib.urlcleanup() before making call to urlopen().http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlcleanup

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a caching issue. A cache is used to optimize communication so common requested data wont need to be requested all the time.

When you call `urllib.open` it uses under the hood the `urlib.retrieve` function. This function caches data locally, so to avoid this caching you should call `urllib.urlcleanup` before each call to `urllib.open`. This is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib)

Also, your question hits the same issue as described in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757168/python-urllib-cache), consider looking it